# How to prevent default cursor style in Dart, Dartium

Tags: dart, dartium

I am trying to prevent the default cursor style for dragging in Dart. In the onDragStart method, I set the cursor style to 'move', and then revert back to the default in onDragEnd:

```
onDragStart(e) {
    prevCursor = placeholder.style.cursor;      
    placeholder.style.cursor = 'move';
}

onDragEnd(e) {
    placeholder.style.cursor = prevCursor;
}
```

When dragging, the cursor still defaults to the 'not-allowed' style. I have tried many methods to prevent this, such as preventing the default to onSelectStart in the onDragStart method, which was recommended as a fix for chromium in javascript, but does not work in Dart:

```
document.onSelectStart.listen( (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

I have also tried setting the default in CSS, which is not how I would like to accomplish this, but it still doesn't work:

```
a:drag {
 cursor:move;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind, there is nothing special about how Dart handles cursors--or basically anything else--for web apps. You might want to Google around for solutions to this problem on regular ol' CSS/Javascript sites. It should be easy to map any solution you find to your Dart code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...just a guess but maybe try to see if maybe you need to also handle onDragEnter?

Answer (score 0):

The drop target sets the cursor icon to "not allowed", if its handlers canceled drag enter event etc. 
Writing the handlers for the drop-zone is the easiest solution.

To circumvent the issue,a mouse down event, mouse move event and so on may be captured and used to move the element like I did here:[Moving elements by dragging in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360151/moving-elements-by-dragging-in-dart/35133073#35133073)

This guy explains the related issue in more detail: http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/

Sort of irrelevant, but with some browsers only use the default cursor icon is available while dragging an element and there is no way to change that default.